# Having trouble displaying my code onto DOM

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having trouble displaying the arrays of books that I have/have not read onto the DOM

```
var booksListArray = [
        {
            title: "Always Running",
            author: "Luis J Rodriguez",
            alreadyRead: true
        },
        {
            title: "Hatchet",
            author: "Gary Paulsen",
            alreadyRead: true
        },
        {
            title: "Autobiography of Malcolm X",
            author: "Malcolm X",
            alreadyRead: true
        },
        {
            title: "Che Guevara: A Revolutionary Life",
            author: "Jon Lee Anderson",
            alreadyRead: false
        },
        {
            title: "The Prince",
            author: "Niccolo Machiavelli",
            alreadyRead: false
        }];

    for (i = 0; i < booksListArray; i++) {
        var currentBook = booksListArray[1];
    };


    if (currentBook.alreadyRead == true) {
       document.write("I have already read " + currentBook.title + " by " + currentBook.author);
    } else {
        document.write("You still have to read " + currentBook.title + " by " + currentBook.author);
    }
```

Comment: What trouble? What's your question?

Comment: You close your loop to early. You do it before first `if`, it should be after `else`.

Comment: Your loop makes no sense, you're just setting `currentBook` (redefining it btw) to the 2nd index in the array X times. Then you use document.write which overwrites the entire DOM, using a possibly undefined variable.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I've having trouble outputting my code onto the html, so in this case, if I  have read a certain book it will  display a specific message, and if i haven't it'll display another. I don't  know if my if  statement is wrong, but I'm not getting anything when I run the code in the browser.

Comment: @Sterling Archer so what could  I do to display the code in a better way?

Comment: Use the DOM. If you look at the documentation and anything, nobody recommends using `document.write`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you wanted to do something like this :

```
for (var i = 0; i < booksListArray.length; i++) {
    var currentBook = booksListArray[i];    
    if (currentBook.alreadyRead == true) {
        document.write("I have already read " + currentBook.title + " by " + currentBook.author);
    } else {
        document.write("You still have to read " + currentBook.title + " by " + currentBook.author);
    }
}
```

There are several mistakes/bad things about your code :
- You are closing the loop too early
- The condition of your loop is not using the `length` of the array
- You need to use `i` to access to your `currentBook`
- Use `var` or `let` to initialize the `i` variable
- You should populate an `HTML element` instead of using `document.write`

Here is a full working example :

```js
var booksListArray = [
{
    title: "Always Running",
    author: "Luis J Rodriguez",
    alreadyRead: true
},
{
    title: "Hatchet",
    author: "Gary Paulsen",
    alreadyRead: true
},
{
    title: "Autobiography of Malcolm X",
    author: "Malcolm X",
    alreadyRead: true
},
{
    title: "Che Guevara: A Revolutionary Life",
    author: "Jon Lee Anderson",
    alreadyRead: false
},
{
    title: "The Prince",
    author: "Niccolo Machiavelli",
    alreadyRead: false
}];

var mydiv = document.getElementById('mylist');
for (var i = 0; i < booksListArray.length; i++) {
    var currentBook = booksListArray[i];    
    if (currentBook.alreadyRead == true) {
     mydiv.innerHTML += "I have already read " + currentBook.title + " by " + currentBook.author + "<br>";
    } else {
     mydiv.innerHTML += "You still have to read " + currentBook.title + " by " + currentBook.author + "<br>";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="mylist"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by I'm closing it too early?

Comment: You are closing the for loop using a bracket `}` before introducing the condition (`if` / `else`)

Comment: Oh okay I see what you mean, now what would  you recommend I do instead of document,write?

Comment: I edited my answer to show you an example using `innerHTML` instead of `document.write`

Comment: Oh okay that works much better, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i = 0; i < booksListArray.length; i++) {
    var currentBook = booksListArray[i]; //index should be i    
    if (currentBook.alreadyRead === true) {
        document.write("I have already read " + currentBook.title + " by " + currentBook.author);
    } else {
        document.write("You still have to read " + currentBook.title + " by " + currentBook.author);
    }
};
```

Comment: Yeah i caught that already,  sorry but I'm still having trouble displaying it